# Post-Redirect-Get for SPAs Best Practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, single-page-application

I've noticed that in creating SPAs, especially when using routing solutions like `ngRoute` and `ui-router` for angularjs or `react-router` for react, implementing a POST which results in a URL (pushState) change is simpler when you use the Post-Redirect-Get pattern. That is, it is simpler to

**(A)** setup the router to *always* defer a state transition until the completion of a GET

than it is to

**(B)** also make it the responsibility of the POST to retrieve the same information we would want from a GET and then have the router skip the GET if that information is there.

Note that the more complex pattern (B) uses just a single POST, while the simpler pattern (A) uses both a POST and a GET.  (A) instantiates the Post-Redirect-Get pattern; (B) does not.

With a traditional multi-page site, the PRG pattern is used to prevent accidental re-submission of form data. But in an SPA, re-submission is not an issue.

However, (A) is easier to implement than (B). Is this reason enough to prefer it?  Are there other reasons to use PRG in an SPA?

What are the best practices when POSTing data in an SPA?